# Power Automate, Attempting to add an action that will paste in and rename an export file according to the previous business day in the MM.DD format

Tags: automation, naming-conventions, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

Currently running into an issue where I need to include an action in the automation script that will paste in a variable in the section to rename a file to include the previous business day in the MM.DD format:

Ultimately, I have the flow set up such that the file is open, and is in the process of saving it out into a specified file directory. The only thing holding me up in the naming convention.

I've attempted to create a variable that includes a function similar to say `formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-1, 'MM.dd'))` but this does not seem to have an effect.

More specifically, I need the flow to work with a Tax lots export file. I would need the file renamed "Tax Lots MM.DD" with the MM.DD being the previous business day.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `formatDateTime`, and without specifying a `<format>` to this, it  will return it in ISO format.

Try just:

```
addDays(utcNow(), -1, 'MM.dd')
```

And if you need it:

```
concat( 'Tax Lots ', addDays(utcNow(), -1, 'MM.dd') )
```